# R function analogous to distanceFromPoints () but for least cost distance

Tags: r, distance, landscape, r-raster

I have a movement model in R that I would like to adapt to incorporate landscape resistance to movement. I'm looking for a way to make a raster surface of least cost values that is analogous to distanceFromPoints() but using least cost distance derived from a user-provided cost raster or transition object instead of euclidean distance, so the output would be a raster or matrix with cell values being least cost distance to a set of points. Using circuitscape resistance might be acceptable as well, but I've never used circuitscape and as far as I understand I would need to constrain the background raster extent to exclude irrelevant cells, which sounds tricky.

I have looked at the movecost and leastcostpath packages in R but neither quite has the option I'm looking for. These packages seem primarily geared towards human movement (using movement algorithms such as Tobler's) across anisotropic slope/dem surfaces, which isn't what I'm interested in (gdistance algorithms would be best for me). This is possible to do using raster to grid to get values for each cell center to each point, but raster to grid is very slow. If there's an easier and faster way I'd be very interested to hear.

Manifold seems to offer a suitable [option](http://www.manifold.net/doc/mfd9/index.htm#raster_paths.htm) but I don't own that software and if possible would like to do everything in R.

The landscapes of interest in the current project are about 6 sq. km extent with 30m pixel resolution and cost values ranging from 1 (most permeable) to 10 (least permeabile) but I would ideally like to be able to use the function in larger areas without it being to arduous in terms of wait time.

Edit: I found a solution! It's a bit rough, but I'll describe it here in case anyone else is looking to do something similar.

```r
#transition object was made using gdistance transition() and then geoCorrection()
#points is a SpatialPoints object showing locations of multiple traps 
#point_names is a vector of names of these traps

cell_coords<-matrix(NA,ncell(transitionobject,2) #make a matrix object in which to store coordinates of all cells in the transitionobject
landscape_costdist_to_traps<-matrix(NA,length(point_names),ncell(transitionobject),dimnames=list(points,NULL))#make a matrix object to store distances from each point to each cell of the transition object

for (i in 1:ncell(transitionobject))
{
  cell_coords[i,]<-xyFromCell(transitionobject,i)
}

for(i in 1:length(point_names))
{
  costdistance_to_trap<-costDistance(transitionobject,cell_coords,points[i,])
  landscape_costdist_to_traps[i,]<-costdistance_to_trap[]
}
```

Comment: Hi @Aman, thanks for your answer. To be honest, I'm not sure what my question is missing from what you listed (and I don't see any comment from MagnusEriksson), but i appreciate your efforts to keep the quality of questions high. I actually figured out a way to accomplish what I wanted so I'll edit my comment in case someone else is looking for something similar.